# Edit the msdeploy generated deploy.cmd file

Tags: asp.net, .net, jenkins, msbuild, msdeploy

The {project}.deploy.cmd file contains commands to be executed by msdeploy.

This auto generated file contains a line that echoes the command that is being executed:

```
 Start executing msdeploy.exe
-------------------------------------------------------
 "...\msdeploy.exe" -source:package='...\mypackage.zip' -dest:auto,computerName="destComp",userName="destCompUsr",password="Pw"
```

This then 'leaks' the password. Is there a way to edit that template to remove the line that echoes the password, or a parameter that turns off the output?

**I am using jenkins to execute msdeploy, and this shows the password on the console output.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to altering the deploy.cmd file have you looked at the Mask Passwords Jenkins plugin [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Mask+Passwords+Plugin)?

If you did want to alter the file it looks like you'll need to remove the echo on the parameter `_MSDeployCommandline` (this is what I find in our project). If you are using Jenkins Pipeline you could use something like AntBuilder to locate and then replace this line.